# How to add AssemblyVersion to every XRay trace as Annotation for both Lambda function and Web APIs

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I would like to add the assembly version to every AWS Xray trace as an annotation for both asp.net core web apis and lambda projects. I want this to be added globally for every request/invocation. How can this be achieved?
I believe this would be two code parts: 1 for lambda, and another for Web API. I imagine the WebAPI would need to have it contained within somewhere in startup.cs middleware, but what about lambda?

Answer (score 0):

1. For WebAPI, you'll need to initialize an instance of AWSXRayRecorder in your request path. Then you can use `AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.AddAnnotation("key", "value")` to add an annotation to the segment of any request that flows through that path. My guess it that you'll need to do this in the controllers rather than the startup.cs since middleware is only registered during application start.
2. For lambda it's a bit tricky. Since you cannot add annotation/metadata to the auto-created segment, you'll need to manually create a subsegment, fetch the subsegment from the context, and use `subsegment.AddAnnotation("key", "value")` to add annotation to the subsegment